# Group By in MySQL - Countries and their respective languages with most popular language on top

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a list of countries called `country`and another table with a list of languages spoken in each country called `countrylanguage`. Both tables have a code for countries that a join can be used on.

I want to `group by` the countries and **show the languages spoken in each country with the highest percentage language at top with the rest descending** underneath it. Example:

```
    Aruba - Papiamento -  76.7 
            English    -  9.5
            Spanish    -  7.4
            Dutch      -  5.3
```

Same for each country in the table.
Below is a sample of 10 rows of each table. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend populating the country column on all rows:

```
select c.name, cl.language, cl.percentage 
from country c join
     countrylanguage cl
     on c.code = cl.countrycode
order by c.name, cl.percentage desc;
```

However, if you really want to skip the country on all but the first row, use `row_number()` and conditional logic:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by c.code order by cl.percentage desc) = 1
             then c.name
        end), cl.language, cl.percentage 
from country c join
     countrylanguage cl
     on c.code = cl.countrycode
order by c.name, cl.percentage desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the second solution is what I was trying to get. Only thing is I am getting null values under each country name but I guess thats okay. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select c.name,cl.language,cl.percentage 
from country c join countrylanguage cl on c.code=cl.countrycode
order by c.name, cl.percentage desc
```

Comment: This gives me two columns - country name and percentage. I am trying to get country, the languages used in that country and then the percentage descending. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @FaisalMalik, updated the answer - you can check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to help you achieve what you ask for;

> *The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.*[¹](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

**Code Syntax**

```
SELECT country.name, countrylanguage.language, countrylanguage.percentage FROM county
LEFT JOIN countrylanguage 
ON country.code = countrylanguage.countryCode
ORDER BY country.name ASC, countrylanguage.percentage DESC
```

**OUTPUT EXAMPLE**

```
|  name |  language  | percentage |
|:-----:|:----------:|:----------:|
| Aruba | Papiamento |    76.7    |
| Aruba |   English  |     9.5    |
| Aruba |   Spanish  |     7.4    |
| Aruba |    Dutch   |     5.3    |
```

**LEFT JOIN Diagram**

[image: left join]

**So, why you can't use `group by` in your query?**

> *The `GROUP BY` statement groups rows that have the same values into summary rows, like "find the number of customers in each country".*
>
> *The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions `(COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG)` to group the result-set by one or more columns.*[²](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

**GROUP BY Syntax**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```